# What happened to Deep Angel?

Tags: fan-fiction, seaquest

A number of years ago, there was a fan fiction site called Deep Angel. It started off as a seaQuest fan fiction story called seaFire ASV, but the story evolved into its own unique canon, featuring a super-cavitating submarine aircraft carrier in the near future.

Suffice it to say, it was awesome. They had a large following with forums, CGI shots, scripts, and even a game in development.

The site, DeepAngel.com, has since gone offline. Does anyone have an idea what happened to it?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It has evolved actually. You will find it is now called Empire Oceans Arise: http://www.empirethefilm.com/

Comment: And you may also be interrested in this page, more info about the seafire ASV: http://atlantisdsv.newcapequest.com/intro.htm

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I had been looking for that on and off for a couple years now. I wonder why they didn't forward their old domain to the new site? I'll upvote when I can - damn daily limit, heh.

Comment: Doh: empirethefilm.com now just hosts generic advert.

Comment: The content might be available at http://208.106.224.177/ — I’m not familiar with it myself, so I’m not sure.

Comment: That domain is completely dead now.

Comment: Looks like they're back as a novel: http://www.empirenovels.com. Copyright shows 2016.

Comment: @ChadLevy - That site is also now dead

Answer (score 3):

The original (archived, released episodes) of **seaFire ASV** are available to be read online [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20110208182741/http://www.newcapequest.com/ncq/). The site's immediate successor; **Atlantis DSV** can also be found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20090107014225/http://atlantisdsv.newcapequest.com/qa.htm).

The site which followed (Empire DSV) has since gone offline. No working backup seems to exist, I'm afraid, but from what I can gather, it was mostly just an archive of the material above anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to have evolved once more to an e-novel called Empire: http://www.empirenovels.com/

The art and story appear to be the same, and the copyright in the footer shows 2016.

Comment: Well, they've certainly cannibalised some of the previous artwork. I don't see that there's a universe connection to DSV on the new site.

Comment: Yeah, I should probably remove the seaQuest tag then since it's an entirely different universe. For me there's still a connection since that's where their story evolved from.